# Statistics of objects in old generation?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvisualvm, jmap

Is there any tool to view object statistics on the different generations of a JVM Heap? I'm looking into a potential memory leak and need some data over the different generations. The use case I have is to take a snapshot over object in old generations, wait, and then take another snapshot to compare.

JVisualVM offers statistics over created object, but that doesn't help me much as I don't see whether or not a particular object is being promoted or tenured faster than it should.

Jmap offers statistics over the different generations, but not on an object basis. In that tool I can only see that the old generation is growing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run your app on Yourkit .It has got generation view tab.You can take snapshots of your heap and compare what objects are still alive between snapshots .

[Documentation](http://www.yourkit.com/features/index.jsp#generations)

Here is an useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335833/java-gc-top-object-classes-promoted-by-size) by @JT .

For more info check this [link](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection/)